# Not able to update ruby version from 1.8.7 to 1.9.2 using rvm

Tags: rvm, ruby-1.9.2, ubuntu-11.10

I am new to ruby programming and want to update ruby from 1.8.7 to 1.9.2. I have followed some steps from different sources but not able to get required result

the sequence of steps are given below

```
#apt-get install ruby-rvm
#rvm remove 1.8.7
#rvm install 1.9.2
#rvm use 1.9.2
Using /usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290
```

after that when i fire #ruby -v, then also it gives the result as given below

```
#ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [i686-linux]
```

Please guide me with specific solution
I am using ubuntu 11.10 beta

Comment: Hey i got the solution, I have fired a command "source /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm" and then go with "type rvm | head -1" and got the output like "rvm is a function". And after that i have run "rvm use 1.9.2 --default" and i got the version of ruby to 1.9.2.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have two installations of rvm, and one of them is broken, please use this answer: [Installed Ruby 1.9.3 with RVM but command line doesn't show ruby -v](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9056008/installed-ruby-1-9-3-with-rvm-but-command-line-doesnt-show-ruby-v/9056395#9056395)