# Install ruby-rvm on Ubuntu 11.10 with ruby 1.9.3

Tags: ruby, rvm

rvm installs properly through:
sudo apt-get install ruby-rvm

When I try to install ruby 1.9.3 I get these errors?

```
anthony@SnakeDoc:~$ rvm install 1.9.3
mkdir: cannot create directory `/usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0': Permission      denied
Installing Ruby from source to: /usr/share/ruby-rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0, this may take   a while depending on your cpu(s)...

ruby-1.9.3-p0 - #fetching 
ruby-1.9.3-p0 - #extracting ruby-1.9.3-p0 to /usr/share/ruby-rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p0
/usr/share/ruby-rvm/scripts/functions/utility: line 142: /usr/share/ruby-rvm/log/ruby-    1.9.3-p0/extract.log: Permission denied
/usr/share/ruby-rvm/scripts/functions/utility: line 148: /usr/share/ruby-rvm/log/ruby-  1.9.3-p0/extract.log: Permission denied
ERROR: Error running 'bunzip2 < '/usr/share/ruby-rvm/archives/ruby-1.9.3-p0.tar.bz2' |   tar xf - -C /usr/share/ruby-rvm/tmp/rvm_src_23435', please read /usr/share/ruby-  rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p0/extract.log
ERROR: There has been an error while trying to extract the source.  
Halting the installation.
ERROR: There has been an error fetching the ruby interpreter. Halting the installation.
```

I tried to chmod the directories where I get access denied but it does not fix the problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: as for the question being closed - it's real problem that users are facing, it is related to the wrong way Ubuntu installs RVM and it is not "off topic"

Comment: voted to reopen since this just happened to me... seems like the people in the ruby tag are being heavy handed lately

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please use this answer: [Installed Ruby 1.9.3 with RVM but command line doesn't show ruby -v](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9056008/installed-ruby-1-9-3-with-rvm-but-command-line-doesnt-show-ruby-v/9056395#9056395)

Your question is not duplicate, but the answer is the same.

Comment: Agreed.  Installing rvm manually seems popular.  I like it because I don't want the package to update itself and mess with my gems.  I also recommend the multi-user install.

Comment: @dgmdan be careful with multi-user installation, in most cases installing as user is just easier and safer choice, I have updated the docs so you might want to get familiar with them: https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/

Comment: This worked for me after I used auto-remove to uninstall all the extra packages