# Permissions error when using gem to install Rails via RVM

Tags: permissions, rubygems, rvm

I'm trying to install Rails using Rubygems via RVM. When running the command `gem install rails -v 3.2.0`, I receive the error:

```
ERROR: While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
You don't have write permissions into the /usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0 directory.
```

I don't want to run it with `sudo` because RVM's website specifically advises against that. Any thoughts why I may be getting this error and how to get around it?

Details:

- RVM version 1.10.2
- Ruby version 1.9.3
- Ubuntu version 11.10

Comment: Well, what are the permissions of that directory? Is this on a server?

Comment: Further, why are you explicitly installing any older version of Rails 3.2? Rails 3.2.1 is out with [several bug fixes](https://gist.github.com/1685812).

Comment: your question is not duplicate but the answer is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9056008/installed-ruby-1-9-3-with-rvm-but-command-line-doesnt-show-ruby-v/9056395#9056395

Comment: @Andrew I don't know what the permissions are (sorry, I'm a bit if a Linux noob). It's a local dev environment. And I'm installing 3.2.0 because I thought that is what I saw on the rails site. Must have made a mistake.

Comment: @mpapis Thanks for the link. I'll give it a shot when I get back on the machine. Just to note, that's the install command I used, so I imagine the important difference is the removal of those two directories when removing rvm.

Comment: @mpapis I ran the `remove` command but when I run `env | grep rvm`, I get back a number of different rvm settings such as `rvm_bin_path`, `rvm_tar`, `rvm_remove_flag`, `rvm_path`, `rvm_uname`, `rvm_prefix`, `PATH`, `rvm_version`, `rvm_ruby_string`, and `rvm_reload`. Could this be because I hadn't installed using `apt-get` in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that after installing rvm and ruby you should issue this command

```
rvm use ruby-1.9.2 --defaults
```

After that you install  rails without any version and don't worry about it

```
gem install rails
```

After installing RVM create gemset directory every time whenever you create separate

project. e.g you create application **blog**. first you create gemset directory with giving

this command and if you want some sepecific version of rails for this application write it

down  to gem file

```
rvm gemset create blog
```

then you should use this gemset directory and also ruby version as well e.g you have install ruby 1.9.2 then use this command

```
  rvm use ruby-1.9.2@blog
```

after that go into directory of blog application and install this gem

```
  gem install bundler
```

and also then bundle install. so all local gem will be installed into this blog directory

under rvm and there will be no conflicts will be appear And also check the rails version it

will be according to gemfile.