# Error in installing rvm in /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm

Tags: rvm

i am trying to set up rvm in my laptop (ubuntu 11.10)

when i gave the command

```
bash -s stable < <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer)
```

its not displaying the installing steps as it did when i ran the same command in my desktop(ubuntu )

and when i gave rvm
or `rvm install 1.9.3`
its throwing error like

```
/usr/bin/rvm: line 54: /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm: No such file or directory
```

i have modified the bashrc and bash_profile using

```
echo '[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

But rvm is not running and throwing errors as

```
/usr/bin/rvm: line 54: /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm: No such file or directory
```

Please suggest me in fixing this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

before you start please clean your system first:

```
rm -rf ~/.rvmrc /etc/rvmrc /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh
```

you can additionally folow this steps: [Installed Ruby 1.9.3 with RVM but command line doesn't show ruby -v](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9056008/installed-ruby-1-9-3-with-rvm-but-command-line-doesnt-show-ruby-v/9056395#9056395)

then open fresh console and make sure no old stuff points to `/usr/local/rvm`:

```
env | grep rvm
```

after it's empty or `~/.rvm` you can run installer again and all should be fine