# Removing RVM on KDE Linux Mint 12 to re-install RVM as single user

Tags: linux, rvm, kde-plasma, linux-mint

I've been having issues installing RVM correctly in a single user environment. RVM keeps giving me errors and I need to just start over. =)

I followed the answer from here: [Installed Ruby 1.9.3 with RVM but command line doesn't show ruby -v](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9056008/installed-ruby-1-9-3-with-rvm-but-command-line-doesnt-show-ruby-v/9056395#9056395)

but when I run `env | grep rvm`
I get this:

```
$ env | grep rvm
rvm_dump_environment_flag=0
rvm_clang_flag=0
rvm_path=/usr/share/ruby-rvm
rvm_prefix=/usr/share
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/share/ruby-rvm/bin:/home/jadmin/.rvm/bin
rvm_version=1.6.9
rvm_reload_flag=0
```

which brings me to believe this is the reason I'm getting this error when trying to install RVM as a single user:

```
bash -s stable < <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer )

mkdir: cannot create directory `/usr/share/ruby-rvm': Permission denied
```

I'm relatively new to ruby & rails, and setting up a dev environment on linux. I appreciate any help =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this answer [Installed Ruby 1.9.3 with RVM but command line doesn't show ruby -v](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9056008/installed-ruby-1-9-3-with-rvm-but-command-line-doesnt-show-ruby-v/9056395#9056395)

It's a problem with apt version of rvm, possibly it will get fixed someday, I was helping someday to improve it ...

Comment: to elaborate, I followed that post correctly, but there is still left-overs of rvm. Can I ignore this and focus on getting past the permissions denied for installing rvm with that bash command?

Comment: Restarted the computer, allowed me to install w/o sudo. Thanks!