# Default Ruby version set with RVM not recognized by system

Tags: ubuntu, rvm

I'm trying to get the system to use the Ruby version I've set with RVM. The following commands produce this output:

```
$ rvm use 1.9.2 --default
Using /usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180
$ rvm current
ruby-1.9.2-p180
$ ruby --version
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]
```

Here's the contents of my PATH:

```
PATH=/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
```

Also:

```
$ whereis ruby
ruby: /usr/bin/ruby /usr/bin/ruby1.8 /usr/lib/ruby /usr/share/man/man1/ruby.1.gz
$ whereis rvm
rvm: /usr/bin/rvm /usr/share/man/man1/rvm.1.gz
```

I assume this is an issue of environmental variables, but I don't really know what to do beyond that.

I've tried `rvm system`, then `rvm list` and `rvm current` only list 1.9.2 with `ruby --version` listing 1.8.7 still.

I've also tried adding `export PATH=/usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180:$PATH` to .bashrc, then restarting and still, the wrong version of RVM. After doing that, my path says:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
```

But if I navigate to `/usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin`, the only executable in the directory is rake. So I figured it just wasn't installed right, so I ran `rvm install 1.9.2` and the directory is still the same.

Comment: Did you install RVM via the package manager (`apt-get`)?

Comment: @AndrewMarshall Honestly, I don't remember. Either that or `gem install`, if that's possible

Comment: RVM is not a gem. Traditionally RVM is installed using its script, however newer versions of Ubuntu include it as a package, which, by the looks of your install location, you are using.

Comment: Then in that case, I almost certainly used apt-get to install it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a mix of two issues - both come from Ubuntu:

1. RVM was installed via apt-get, to solve use: [Installed Ruby 1.9.3 with RVM but command line doesn't show ruby -v](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9056008/installed-ruby-1-9-3-with-rvm-but-command-line-doesnt-show-ruby-v/9056395#9056395)
2. You are using gnome-terminal, to solve use: https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal/