# setting classpath using setenv.sh for a project

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, centos, redhat

I want to write an sh file that will set classpath in Linux.

I tried using:

```
export ClASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$ABC_HOME
```

However, when I run the .sh file it doesn't set the classpath.

Answer (score 1):

Executing the bash script only sets the environment for the child process.  The "source" command may do what you want...

https://askubuntu.com/questions/53177/bash-script-to-set-environment-variables-not-working

Answer (score 0):

You should make it a shell function, or `source` it. Because the environment variables are local to the shell (the one started by invoking your shell script).

Please read the [advanced bash scripting guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/). See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12650667/841108) to a similar question.

Comment: actually i need to deliver sh file as part of project deliverable , don't know much about shell function