# Bash script says command not found

Tags: bash, centos

I try to run the following bash script to create a bunch of users, groups, home dirs for the users and correct permissions for all of these. The OS is CentOS.

When I try to run the following, which I though should work, it returns "command not found" when running via terminal. it only gets as far as creating the /homedirs directory, nothing more. I'm a total noob at bash scripting so forgive me if this looks ugly.

```
mkdir /homedirs; chmod 775 /homedirs;

for iYear in {1..3} do
    sYear = $iYear"ti"
    sYearDir = "/homerirs/"$sYear
    groupadd $sYear; mkdir $sYearDir; chgrp $sYear $sYearDir; chmod 750 $sYearDir

    for sClass in {a,b} do
        sClassDir = $sYearDir/$sClass
        mkdir $sClassDir
        sClassGrp = $sYear$sClass
        groupadd $sClassGrp; chgrp $sClassGrp $sClassDir; chmod 750 $sClassDir

        for iUser in {1..3} do
            sUserName = "i"$iYear$sClass"g"$iUser
            sUserDir = $sClassDir/$sUserName
            useradd -d $sUserDir -g $sClassGrp -G $sYear -m $sUserName
            chown $sUserName $sUserDir; chmod 750 $sUserDir
        done
    done
done
```

Comment: Doesn't it have to be `for ... in ... ; do`, with semicolons separating flow control statement and `do` block?

Comment: @raina77ow that could be. I'm still quite unfamliar with the syntax. In fact I think it should be, too, come to think of it. Edit: that didn't solve the problem...

Comment: `for iYear in 1 2 3; do` and `for sClass in a b; do` would not only be shorter, but also more portable.

Comment: You might want to fix the spelling of `homerirs` too.

Comment: @raina77ow: +1 Yes you do need semicolons.

Comment: Hmm. Can you do this `cat scriptname.sh | sed 's/\r/<CR>/'`, when `scriptname.sh` is your script filename?

Comment: @tripleee I cannot believe I've overlooked that...

Comment: Or just run `dos2unix` on that script, and try to run it again... See, it's weird having it execute just the first line, and then stop with 'Command not found'.

Comment: Your variable names got translated into Dutch (?) somewhere halfway. You must have a very dangerous computer virus (-:

Comment: @tripleee no, the original variable names were in Dutch. I changed them here to be more readable to answerers.

Comment: I don't think you need to `chown` the directory created by `useradd` and it should hopefully already have the right permissions, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is caused by the spaces around the equals signs. A token with whitespace after it is interpreted as a command name; so what you intended as variable names causes the `Command not found` errors.

Comment: Can you also tell me how to login with these users? As you can see, no password was specified but the login screen or terminal ask me for a password. When I leave it blank, there's an authentication failure...

Comment: You should probably pass in a password with an option to `useradd`. To change the password of an existing user, run `passwd $user` as root.

Comment: ... or install a suitable public SSH key and leave them passwordless.

Comment: I don't really get what you mean with that last. The teacher (yes, this is for school) just asked us to script this and he said don't give a password with useradd. We have only had a poor introduction to unix last year...

Comment: If it's just for demonstration, you can access an account with `su - $user`.  Normally a (non-system) account with no way to log in is useless.  You have to have either a password or some alternate means of authentication, such as an SSH keypair.  Kerberos is also popular in some organizations.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to set your `PATH` and you really should read the [advanced bash scripting guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/). See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12650661/ruby-in-linux-permanently-source-rvm-scripts-rvm/12650667#12650667).

I also suggest to debug your script by starting it with `#!/bin/bash -vx` as its first line. And you should make it executable with `chmod u+x` at least.

Perhaps `groupadd` might not be available on your system.

Comment: I've also made it executable... Groupadd is available.

Comment: Okay, I cannot run it from the terminal as opposed to what I thought before. What more do I need to do beside chmod u+x ?

Answer (score -1):

best thing to do is add the full path before your executables:

change useradd to  /usr/sbin/useradd

change groupadd to /usr/sbin/groupadd

will cure the command not found.

remember this programs will probably need to run as root  to work.

Comment: -1 No, don't do that. Set up a sane `PATH` once, and never hard-code command path names.

Comment: Thanks for the run as root hint, didn't know if it was necessary but did it anyway.