# 'rvm get head' unrecognized command line argument: 'get' (see: 'rvm usage') on Ubuntu 11.10 oneric

Tags: rvm

I have following version of rvm installed on ubuntu 11.0.

```
$ rvm -v
rvm 1.0.1 by Wayne E. Seguin (wayneeseguin@gmail.com) [http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/]
```

However, on running rvm get head, I am getting following errors.

```
$ rvm get head && rvm reload
fail: Unrecognized command line argument: 'get' ( see: 'rvm usage' )

$ rvm update --head
rvm 1.0.1 by Wayne E. Seguin (wayneeseguin@gmail.com) [http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/]
fatal: destination path 'rvm' already exists and is not an empty directory.
fatal: destination path 'rvm' already exists and is not an empty directory.
```

Can you help me find out what is the problem? and what to do to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have very old RVM installation, probably from Ubuntu, use this answer:

[Installed Ruby 1.9.3 with RVM but command line doesn't show ruby -v](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9056008/installed-ruby-1-9-3-with-rvm-but-command-line-doesnt-show-ruby-v/9056395#9056395)

It will help you clean your system and install stable version of RVM.

As a hint, you could use following command to install RVM, Ruby and Rails in one hit:

```
curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -i stable --rails --auto
```