# Why isn't .rvmrc working on Ubuntu?

Tags: ruby, rake, rvm

I am trying to get Ruby and RVM working on my Ubuntu system, but I am experiencing strange behaviour.
I am a new to Ruby, so I may have missed something basic.

I cloned octopress into a folder, and there is a `.rvmrc` file in there that contains:

```
rvm use 1.9.2
```

The thing is that when I enter the folder, the file is not taken into account. If I run:

```
ruby --version
```

I get:

```
ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [x86_64-linux]
```

I tried:

```
./.rvmrc
```

and:

```
rvm reload
```

It seems to work, as I get:

```
Using /usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320
Running /usr/share/ruby-rvm/hooks/after_cd
Using /usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320
```

as a result. However, running `ruby --version` again does not change anything.

The really strange thing is that everything works fine If I connect myself to my localhost using `ssh`.

I installed Rake using "[Installing RVM on Linux](http://ruby.about.com/od/rubyversionmanager/ss/installrvmlinux_4.htm)".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution here :

[Installed Ruby 1.9.3 with RVM but command line doesn't show ruby -v](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9056008/installed-ruby-1-9-3-with-rvm-but-command-line-doesnt-show-ruby-v/9056395#9056395)

Thanks Jim for having pointed me to the documentation. I found lots of great stuff in there :).

Answer (score 1):

You are probably running into issues due to recent changes in how RVM expects to be loaded (the method in that link isn't correct IIRC). Follow the steps at https://rvm.io/rvm/upgrading/. Also, use `rvm get stable --auto` to properly configure your bash scripts

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Which command should I use? I tried rvm get stable --auto but it doesn't seem to change anything by itself :s

Comment: if you just installed, then rvm get stable --auto won't change anything in the rvm code, but it will modify your .bash* startup files to reflect the correct config. Try logging out and back in, and if that doesn't work, it may be worth reading through the help on rvm.io, and/or looking for help on the #rvm IRC channel

Comment: Ok, Thanks for the help. I'll have a closer look at this tonight. What I really don't get is that everything works fine through ssh. When directly using commands in a terminal, I get errors for all my rake/bundle commands. There must be a logical reason for this :).