# bash issue installing rvm on ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: ruby, bash, rvm, ubuntu-12.04

I am completely new to Linux and am having trouble installing rvm. From https://rvm.io/rvm/install/, I run

```
$ curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
```

in terminal. I receive the following error:

```
bash: line 359: /usr/share/ruby-rvm/RELEASE: Permission denied
```

I don't know which file line 359 refers to. What is going on here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using rvm settings broken by ubuntu, this package is not mainatined, please use this instruction to fix:
[Installed Ruby 1.9.3 with RVM but command line doesn't show ruby -v](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9056008/installed-ruby-1-9-3-with-rvm-but-command-line-doesnt-show-ruby-v/9056395#9056395)