# not success to get rails --version from ubuntu 11.04 console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I have Ubuntu 11.04, + Ruby 1.9.3-p125

I have installed Rails in 2 ways:

- `rvm gem install rails`
- `gem install rails`

When I want to check the version of Rails I'm using:

```
rails --version
```

I get the error:

> The program 'rails' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing: `sudo apt-get install rails`

Comment: Have you rebooted your machine?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the RVM ruby version is in your PATH.

Comment: I believe to check you can use ```echo $PATH```.  If you need to added it but, don't know where it is, try to find it ```find / -name ruby```.  If you find it you can added it like so ```export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/ruby```

Comment: Also, did you follow the instructions after installing RVM to add it to all open shells?  You can also try ```rvm use 1.9.3``` and retry your installs.

Comment: @TravisPessetto Though I suspect that he's getting the correct `ruby` since his `ruby --version` is 1.9.3, but it definitely seems RVM was not correctly installed.

Answer (score 1):

If you have just installed rvm, then even though you have not installed rails, you are not "using" a gemset. If you run `rvm gemset list` you will notice a list of gemsets (probably just 'global'), with no star next to any of them.

You first need to use a gemset before you can see what version a gem is in that gemset. Try something like `rvm use @global` to use the 'global' gemset. Then you will see something on your terminal like `Using /home/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125 with gemset global`. Now if you try doing `rails -v` It should give you your version number

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

you need to **use ruby** before doing any work with it:

```
rvm use 1.9.3-p125
```

now you can just run any commands without prefixing them with `rvm`:

```
gem install rails
rails new test1
```

when you did prefix command with rvm it was actually short for:

```
rvm all do gem install rails
```

which means install gem rails into all rubies @default gemset.

you could be also victim of old and broken RVM installation bundled with Ubuntu, have a look on this answer for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9056395/497756

Also you should get known with some details how to use RVM, you should find this short tutorial very resourceful: http://screencasts.org/episodes/how-to-use-rvm

Comment: Thanks, I am doing:rvm use 1.9.3-p125 -> get error: RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.

Comment: make sure you update RVM(`rvm get stable --auto`), it will then give you more meaningful messages, just read them and follow the instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Try `which rails` in terminal to know the path.

It should be `/usr/bin/rails`. If not try `export PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH`.