# ERROR: While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ubuntu

forgive me but i'm new to the world of linux still learning.I'm using rvm and ruby 2 under ubuntu 13.04 my problem is that i can't upgrade rails.

`gem install rails`

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
You don't have write permissions for the /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0 directory.
```

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11092690/rvm-gem-permissions-error