# Installing Ruby 1.9.2 on Ubuntu via RVM

Tags: ruby, linux, ubuntu, rvm

Trying to install and use ruby 1.9.2 on my server. Running Ubuntu 11.10.

```
    $ rvm use 1.9.2
    Using /usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180
    $ ruby -v
    ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [i686-linux]
```

Wait...what?

Comment: Have you installed Ruby before, without RVM (using apt get for instance)? Have you tried `rvm use 1.9.2 --default` ?

Comment: what is the output of `which ruby` ?

Comment: What shell are you using?

How did you install RVM?

Where are you sourcing RVM? Meaning, to which file did you add ```[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"``` ?

Comment: 1.8.7 was installed without RVM.   rvm use 1.9.2 --default worked. Thanks!

I guess I'm just using the default shell through SSH connection.

Comment: @unmuse np. glad you got it working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below are the steps for a fresh installation if you need it at any time:

bash -sk stable < <(curl -sk https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer)

echo '[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function' >> ~/.bash_profile

source ~/.bash_profile

source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh

rvm requirements #Lets you know the system dependencies and if you need to install any other libraries

rvm install 1.9.2-p290

rvm use 1.9.2 --default

rvm gemset create demo

rvm demo@1.9.2

then install rails

gem install rails -v=3.0.4

If at any time u mess up your rvm you can remove it using rvm implode or rm -rf ~/.rvm

Answer (score 0):

You are using buggy version of RVM, use this instructions to install proper version: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9056395/497756