# Difficulties after installing rvm

Tags: ruby, rvm, dpkg

I have installed rvm properly.

However, I keep getting this error every time I install something:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:

ruby-rvm

Error in function: 

Setting up ruby-rvm (1.6.9-0ubuntu2) ...

dpkg-statoverride: error: syntax error: unknown group 'admin' in statoverride file

dpkg: error processing ruby-rvm (--configure):

subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status
```

Comment: @PedroNascimento ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Answer (score 2):

you should not use rvm packaged by ubuntu, it's old and ships with issues that are fixed in rvm already but the package was not updated to use the stable version.

Use this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9056395/497756 to fix.

Comment: This is how i installed rvm. Still getting errors


curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable

Comment: make sure to follow all instructions from the link, double check you removed everything. rvm by itself does not call dpkg - so your error can not be generated by RVM!