# Error on installing ruby rvm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu-12.04

On [installing Ruby1.9.3 with RVM](http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/) `rvm install 1.9.3`, It show following message.

```
The program 'rvm' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install ruby-rvm
```

After that I had tried to install ruby-rvm but it shows following message at last.

```
...
Setting up libreadline-gplv2-dev (5.2-11) ...
Setting up ruby-rvm (1.6.9-0ubuntu2) ...
dpkg-statoverride: error: syntax error: unknown group 'admin' in statoverride file
dpkg: error processing ruby-rvm (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ruby-rvm
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

after receving this message I look up at [here](https://rvm.io//rubies/installing/) but I don't able to figure what above error code means.

```
virus@virus-pc:~$ source /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm

virus@virus-pc:~$ type rvm | head -1
rvm is a function

virus@virus-pc:~$ rvm use 1.9.3 --default
ruby-1.9.3-p194 is not installed.
To install do: 'rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p194'

virus@virus-pc:~$ rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p194
ruby-1.9.3-p194 - #configure
ruby-1.9.3-p194 - #download
Archive checksum did not match, downloading again.
rm: cannot remove `bin-ruby-1.9.3-p194.tar.bz2': Permission denied
curl: Can't open 'bin-ruby-1.9.3-p194.tar.bz2'!
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
There was an error(23), please check /usr/local/rvm/log//*.log. Next we'll try to fetch via http.
Trying ftp:// URL instead.
curl: Can't open 'bin-ruby-1.9.3-p194.tar.bz2'!
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
There was an error(23), please check /usr/local/rvm/log//*.log
Downloading https://rvm.io/binaries/ubuntu/12.04/x86_64/ruby-1.9.3-p194.tar.bz2 failed.
Mounting remote ruby failed, trying to compile.
Installing Ruby from source to: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-1.9.3-p194 - #downloading ruby-1.9.3-p194, this may take a while depending on your connection...
mkdir: cannot create directory `/usr/local/rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p194': Permission denied
tee: /usr/local/rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p194/fetch.log: No such file or directory
bash: /usr/local/rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p194/fetch.log: No such file or directory
Error running '/usr/local/rvm/scripts/fetch http://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.9/ruby-1.9.3-p194.tar.bz2', please read /usr/local/rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p194/fetch.log
There has been an error fetching the ruby interpreter. Halting the installation.
bash: /usr/local/rvm/user/installs.new: Permission denied
mv: cannot stat `/usr/local/rvm/user/installs.new': No such file or directory
bash: /usr/local/rvm/user/installs: Permission denied
```

I had tried to install it and wasted 3 days but couldn't able to succeed on installing ruby on rails and tackle above error.As I'm new to ruby any help were appreciated.

Environment: Ubuntu-12.04 64 bits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to install it with `apt-get`. You probably installed ruby-rvm but since it's outdated it was installed broken. You probably have to delete it using synaptic or via `sudo apt-get purge ruby-rvm` command. You should NOT install rvm via `apt-get`. Read post from Ryan more careful. Correct command to install rvm is:

> curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable

Comment: thanks for response I already had tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9056008/installed-ruby-1-9-3-with-rvm-but-command-line-doesnt-show-ruby-v) and now I feel I'm in loop.

Answer (score 1):

\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby

note backslash before curl