# How to remove Ubuntu stock Ruby 1.8? Not apt

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rvm

Ubuntu came with Ruby 1.8 installed, but I really would rather (and need, for rails) 1.9.2. I tried `apt-get purge` but apt doesn't believe there is a ruby package (however `ruby -v` keeps returning ruby 1.8).

I have installed rvm but `ruby -v` now only returns `bash: /usr/bin/ruby: No such file or directory`. I'm lost, any help?

I removed ruby from `/usr/bin` but it refuses to accept that rvm exists and keeps suggesting i install the 1.8 or 1.9.1 packages.

Comment: try apt-get remove ruby or remove the ruby variable from your enviroment path

Comment: It's ok. to use the built-in package system, you'll need to remove v. 1.8 and install 1.9 (either 1.9.1 or 1.9.3, even if it's 1.9.1, it's actually 1.9.3).

Comment: I just installed the 1.9.3 package and `ruby -v` is returning `ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]`

Comment: latest update- clean slate, reinstalled rvm, 1.9.2 installed and using, ruby -v returning 1.9.2. All solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RVM is a bit wonky on Ubuntu.  Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9056395/399584) for a fix before going any further.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to a GUI, try running The Synaptics Packet Manager

I had the same problem and Synaptics marked ruby 1.8 as installed. Unchecked the package, clicked on run and ruby was GONE

`$ ruby -v` now yields command not found

Now you can safely run

```
$ apt-get install rubyX.X.X
```

Happy coding!