# RVM not using installed gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

Any idea how to resolve?

Take a look at this:

```
funkdified@vizio ~/rails_projects/goodsounds.org $ rvm current
ruby-1.9.3-p392@goodsounds
funkdified@vizio ~/rails_projects/goodsounds.org $ gem install bundler
Fetching: bundler-1.3.2.gem (100%)
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied - /var/lib/gems
funkdified@vizio ~/rails_projects/goodsounds.org $ rvm gemset list

gemsets for ruby-1.9.3-p392 (found in /home/funkdified/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392)
   (default)
   global
=> goodsounds

funkdified@vizio ~/rails_projects/goodsounds.org $ rvm @goodsounds do gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (3.2.13.rc1)
actionpack (3.2.13.rc1)
activemodel (3.2.13.rc1)
activerecord (3.2.13.rc1)
activeresource (3.2.13.rc1)
activesupport (3.2.13.rc1)
acts-as-taggable-on (2.3.3)
annotate (2.4.1.beta1)
arel (3.0.2)
awesome_print (1.1.0)
bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
better_errors (0.7.0)
binding_of_caller (0.7.1)
blankslate (3.1.2)
bootstrap-sass (2.3.0.1)
bootstrap-will_paginate (0.0.9)
builder (3.0.4)
bundler (1.3.2)
cancan (1.6.8)
celluloid (0.12.4)
chronic (0.9.1)
climate_control (0.0.3)
cocaine (0.5.1)
coderay (1.0.9)
coffee-rails (3.2.2)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.5.0)
columnize (0.3.6)
connection_pool (1.0.0)
country_select (1.1.3)
daemons (1.1.9)
debug_inspector (0.0.2)
debugger (1.2.4)
debugger-linecache (1.1.2)
debugger-ruby_core_source (1.1.9)
decorators (1.0.3)
devise (2.2.3)
diff-lcs (1.2.1)
erubis (2.7.0)
eventmachine (1.0.1)
execjs (1.4.0)
facter (1.6.17)
factory_girl (4.2.0)
factory_girl_rails (4.2.1)
fastthread (1.0.7)
ffi (1.0.11)
font-awesome-sass-rails (3.0.2.2)
forem-redcarpet (1.0.0)
friendly_id (4.0.9)
gemoji (1.1.2)
geocoder (1.1.6)
gmaps4rails (1.5.6)
gon (4.0.2)
google_visualr (2.1.7)
googlecharts (1.6.8)
guard (1.6.2)
guard-rspec (2.5.0)
haml (4.0.0)
hash-deep-merge (0.1.1)
hike (1.2.1)
i18n (0.6.1)
journey (1.0.4)
jquery-rails (2.2.1)
jquery-ui-rails (3.0.1)
json (1.7.7)
kaminari (0.14.1)
lazy_high_charts (1.3.3)
libnotify (0.8.0)
libv8 (3.11.8.13 x86_64-linux)
listen (0.7.3)
lumberjack (1.0.2)
mail (2.5.3)
meta_request (0.2.0)
method_source (0.8.1)
mime-types (1.21)
multi_json (1.6.1)
nested_form (0.3.1)
nifty-generators (0.4.6)
nokogiri (1.5.6)
orm_adapter (0.4.0)
pg (0.14.1, 0.13.2)
polyamorous (0.5.0)
polyglot (0.3.3)
pry (0.9.12)
pry-debugger (0.2.1)
pygments.rb (0.2.4)
quiet_assets (1.0.2)
rack (1.4.5)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-contrib (1.1.0)
rack-pjax (0.7.0)
rack-ssl (1.3.3)
rack-test (0.6.2)
rails (3.2.13.rc1)
rails_admin (0.4.5)
railties (3.2.13.rc1)
rake (10.0.3)
rdoc (3.12.2)
redcarpet (2.0.1)
RedCloth (4.2.9)
redis (3.0.3)
redis-namespace (1.2.1)
ref (1.0.2)
remotipart (1.0.5)
rest-client (1.6.7)
rolify (3.2.0)
rspec (2.13.0)
rspec-core (2.13.0)
rspec-expectations (2.13.0)
rspec-mocks (2.13.0)
rspec-rails (2.13.0)
rubygems-bundler (1.1.1)
rubypython (0.5.3)
rvm (1.11.3.6)
safe_yaml (0.8.4)
sass (3.2.6)
sass-rails (3.2.6)
select2-rails (3.3.0)
sequel (3.20.0)
sidekiq (2.8.0)
simple_form (2.1.0)
sinatra (1.0)
slim (1.3.6)
slop (3.4.3)
sprockets (2.2.2)
squeel (1.0.17)
taps (0.3.24)
temple (0.5.5)
terminal-table (1.4.5)
therubyracer (0.11.4)
thin (1.5.0)
thor (0.17.0)
tilt (1.3.4)
timers (1.1.0)
treetop (1.4.12)
tzinfo (0.3.36)
uglifier (1.3.0)
v (0.1.1)
warden (1.2.1)
webrat (0.7.3)
whenever (0.8.2)
will_paginate (3.0.4)
workflow (0.8.0)
funkdified@vizio ~/rails_projects/goodsounds.org $ bundle
ERROR: Gem bundler is not installed, run `gem install bundler` first.
```

Comment: Open terminal and go to `Edit` and select `Profile preferences`.. It will show pop up. Then select `Title and Command` tab and uncheck `Run command as login shell`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to select the "Run command as login shell" inside of gnome terminal!

As the comment above suggests:

> Open terminal and go to Edit and select Profile preferences.. It will
>   show pop up. Then select Title and Command tab and uncheck Run command
>   as login shell

Answer (score 1):

It might be an issue is with the installation of bundler and permission to execute bundle command.

```
funkdified@vizio ~/rails_projects/goodsounds.org $ gem install bundler
Fetching: bundler-1.3.2.gem (100%)
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied - /var/lib/gems
funkdified@vizio ~/rails_projects/goods
```

Did you install anything ruby/gem via system's package manager or used sudo during gem installation?

This question have similar issue, i.e [rvm and bundle install in Ubuntu 12.10: Errno::EACCES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13055062/rvm-and-bundle-install-in-ubuntu-12-10-errnoeacces)  and this to install rvm properly [Installed Ruby 1.9.3 with RVM but command line doesn't show ruby -v](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9056008/installed-ruby-1-9-3-with-rvm-but-command-line-doesnt-show-ruby-v).

Answer (score 0):

do you have root access?

if so, try:

```
sudo gem install bundler
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue here is that you do not have permission to install to /var/lib/gems. Have your tried performing an install as 'root':

> `sudo gem install bundler`

If you didn't install rvm as a user install, then you will not be able to install gems without sudo.