# Ubuntu's rvm ruby and openssl

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, compilation, openssl, rvm

I am trying to install ruby with rvm on Ubuntu. I installed rvm with the synaptic package manager.

```
$ which rvm
/usr/bin/rvm
$ rvm --version

rvm 1.6.9 by Wayne E. Seguin (wayneeseguin@gmail.com) [https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/]
```

I try to install ruby:

```
$ rvm install 1.9.2
...
ERROR: Error running 'make ', please read /usr/share/ruby-rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p180/make.log
ERROR: There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

The problem in the logfile is openssl related:

```
ossl_ssl.c:110:1: error: ‘SSLv2_method’ undeclared here (not in a function)
```

On https://rvm.io/packages/openssl/ it says to do `$ rvm requirements` but it gives an error:

```
$ rvm requirements
ERROR: Unrecognized command line argument: 'requirements' ( see: 'rvm usage' )
```

On the same page, it asks to do `$ rvm reinstall 1.9.2 --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local`, but this gives me the same errors during ruby's compilation. For the second approach on the same page, doing `rvm pkg install openssl` gives me

```
$ rvm pkg install openssl
ERROR: Unrecognized command line argument: 'pkg' ( see: 'rvm usage' )
```

Openssl is apparently installed:

```
$ dpkg --get-selections | grep openssl
openssl                     install
python-openssl              install
```

Comment: Don't don't don't install rvm with the package manager, use the installer scripts provided. See http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/ for a good tutorial on doing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're running an outdated version of RVM. You should go with the recommended install path explained on http://rvm.io and don't use a package installer. To fix check this instruction https://stackoverflow.com/a/9056395/497756.

Also don't use 1.9.2 use the current 1.9.3 ruby instead and for new projects use 2.0.0 which is in RC1 and should be released soon.

Answer (score 1):

if you use ubuntu, just use ruby from this ppa..

```
http://blog.brightbox.co.uk/posts/next-generation-ruby-packages-for-ubuntu
```