# Not able to execute any rails or rake command

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

When I try to execute any command, 
e.g. `rake secret` or `rails server`

I get the following error and `rake` is aborted:

> The method `YAML.enable_arbitrary_object_deserialization!` is deprecated and will be removed in the next release of SafeYAML -- set the `SafeYAML::OPTIONS[:default_mode]` to either `:safe` or `:unsafe`.

Please advise. (I am a Ruby on Rails newbie).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following:

```
1- Go to the root of your application.
2- From there, go to the `config` folder and open the `environment.rb`
3- Put `SafeYAML::OPTIONS[:deserialize_symbols] = true`
4- Try again.
```

That's a known issue listed in the Safe_Yaml gem: https://github.com/dtao/safe_yaml (See known issues section)

Comment: Thanks fmendez! But I am still getting the warning after adding that to environment.rb

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was using the wrong version of ruby and my rvm was broken.
Also, my .rvmrc file was not bieng executed correctly.

1. I followed instructions at 
   [Installed Ruby 1.9.3 with RVM but command line doesn't show ruby -v](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9056008/installed-ruby-1-9-3-with-rvm-but-command-line-doesnt-show-ruby-v/9056395#9056395)
   and rebuild my RVM
2. Then integrated rvm with my shell:
   https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal/
3. Installed correct version of ruby for my project:
   rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p374

I still get the 'YAML.enable..." warning, but the commands do execute now.