# RVM Ruby on Rails installation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, ubuntu-12.04

I'm having a trouble installing rvm ROR on my machine using ubuntu 12.04

here are the outputs I'm getting:

Output #1:

```
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: ubuntu/12.04/i386/ruby-1.8.7-p371.Continuing with compilation. 
Please read 'rvm mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Installing requirements for ubuntu, might require sudo password.
```

and at the end of the line of update I get this:

Output #2:

```
There has been error while updating 'apt-get', please give it some time and try again later.
For 404 errors check your sources configured in:
/etc/apt/sources.list
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list
```

Comment: You are using old and broken (by Ubuntu) . try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9056395/1297435)

Comment: @anonymousxxx What do you mean? What should I do?

Comment: Have you seen link on my comment?

Comment: It didn't install ruby. It only updated and showed me output #2.

Comment: have you run `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install build-essential` ?

Comment: Yes I have already run those commands.

Comment: probably it would be good,if you post the step by step installation process, what you did for your own installation

Comment: I've seen another post solving this issue. But the steps is about disabling third party ppa. How can I disable that? I always end up in output #2 when running: rvm install 1.8.7.

Comment: It seems to be working now. Thanks for the link. I can use it for fresh install on another unit.

Comment: Try changing the repository to the main server and try this out
http://stackoverflow.com/a/17381649/1581519

Answer (score 22):

Try running `sudo apt-get update` separately on a command line. Your Ubuntu might be old and its repositories could be out of date. So `apt-get update` itself is maybe not working in your machine.

To step over that issue, run the following commands:

```
# Disable RVM from trying to install necessary software via apt-get
rvm autolibs disable

# Then try installing Ruby:
rvm install 1.8.7
```

If you still face errors, see if you can directly do `apt-get install` without doing `apt-get update` (which fails):

```
# Try to see if you can manually install the necessary software
sudo apt-get install build-essential openssl libreadline6 libreadline6-dev curl git-core zlib1g zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt-dev autoconf libc6-dev ncurses-dev automake libtool bison subversion pkg-config
```

If that's also not working, then paste your `apt-get update` output.