# Error in rvm requirements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, failed-installation

I am following this guide to install Ruby on Rails. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin-with-rvm

When I do rvm requirements, I am getting this error:

```
$ rvm requirements
Checking requirements for ubuntu.
Installing requirements for ubuntu.
Updating system...................
Error running 'requirements_debian_update_system ',
showing last 15 lines of /home/icts/.rvm/log/1396698452/update_system.log
+ case "${TERM:-dumb}" in
+ case "$1" in
+ [[ -t 2 ]]
+ return 1
+ printf %b 'There has been error while updating '\''apt-get'\'', please give it some time and try again later.
For 404 errors check your sources configured in:
    /etc/apt/sources.list
    /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list
\n'
There has been error while updating 'apt-get', please give it some time and try again later.
For 404 errors check your sources configured in:
    /etc/apt/sources.list
    /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list

+ return 100
Requirements installation failed with status: 100.
```

Can anyone help me what I am going wrong?

Comment: you have problem in updating packages for your debian, not in installing rvm.

Comment: Ok. I understand that. Any idea how i can fix it?

Comment: What's the version of your ubuntu? 12.04?

Comment: just run `sudo apt-get update`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have to keep RVM from installing required libraries and do it on your own. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16758143/rvm-ruby-on-rails-installation) for more information. As you know, every version of ubuntu is unique. You may want to try a solution for 12.04 just like you first did. You may also want to run `rvm get stable` first and specify a stable version of ruby as well unless you have something else on your mind.