# Ruby RVM apt-get update error

Tags: ruby, rvm

I get following error when trying to install anything with RVM:

```
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
Found remote file https://rvm.io/binaries/ubuntu/13.04/x86_64/ruby-2.1.1.tar.bz2
Checking requirements for ubuntu.
Installing requirements for ubuntu.
Updating system..kshitiz password required for 'apt-get --quiet --yes update': 
............................
Error running 'requirements_debian_update_system ruby-2.1.1',
showing last 15 lines of /home/kshitiz/.rvm/log/1400047196_ruby-2.1.1/update_system.log
++ /scripts/functions/logging : rvm_pretty_print()  78 > case "${TERM:-dumb}" in
++ /scripts/functions/logging : rvm_pretty_print()  81 > case "$1" in
++ /scripts/functions/logging : rvm_pretty_print()  83 > [[ -t 2 ]]
++ /scripts/functions/logging : rvm_pretty_print()  83 > return 1
++ /scripts/functions/logging : rvm_error()  117 > printf %b 'There has been error while updating '\''apt-get'\'', please give it some time and try again later.
For 404 errors check your sources configured in:
    /etc/apt/sources.list
    /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list
\n'
There has been error while updating 'apt-get', please give it some time and try again later.
For 404 errors check your sources configured in:
    /etc/apt/sources.list
    /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list

++ /scripts/functions/requirements/ubuntu : requirements_debian_update_system()  53 > return 100
Requirements installation failed with status: 100.
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

`RVM` doesn't behave well if `apt-get update` has errors. If your `apt` `sources` have an invalid repository that gives 404 or GPG error, `RVM` will refuse to work. This can be confusing because it happens even if the faulty repository has nothing to do with `ruby` or `RVM`.

The following fix worked for me (Ubuntu):

Run `apt-get update` and see if there are any errors. Edit your `sources.list` and `precise.list` in `/etc/apt` to remove the faulty repositories. Repeat until `apt-get update` succeeds without any errors. Then try running `RVM`.

Comment: Your answer makes sense.  I'm applying this technique now.

Comment: I want to give a bounty :) Exactly as explained, some ppa were returning 404 and there were few warnings. Fixed them and it worked like a charm.

Comment: In my case, `apt-get update` did throw errors but I couldn't find them in `/etc/apt/sources.list` (`/etc/apt/precise.list` doesn't even exists in my system). Poking around I've found some files for specific applications in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` and the errors were coming from there. I removed (backed up and moved) the files that were causing the problem and it worked.

Comment: So you can get this error also, if you have locked package manager

Comment: Completely fixed this for me. I had some weird source on in my lists which 404'd

Comment: Message from the future.  I have this same problem but `sudo apt-get update` does not produce any errors, so there's nothing to fix there.

Comment: @MatthewJamesBriggs In that case the error message you are getting must differ in some way. Can you post the error on paste bin?

Comment: @KshitizSharma I eventually resolved it by installation by the dedicated Ubuntu package of rvm with apt-get and it worked.

Answer (score 68):

You can try to skip the rvm updating system so apt-get won't be called.

```
# Disable RVM from trying to install necessary software via apt-get
rvm autolibs disable

# Then try installing Ruby:
rvm install 2.4.0
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/16759839/1212791

Answer (score 39):

I also had to remove failing repositories but I had hard time spotting them and removing them based on instructions here. So I found this [link](http://ask.xmodulo.com/find-remove-obsolete-ppa-repositories-ubuntu.html) which explains exactly why this happens and how to remove failing repositories:

In short, run following to find failing repositories:

```
sudo apt-get update | grep "Failed"
```

An example output can be like this:

```
:~# apt-get update  | grep "Failed"
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/web/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/web/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

And finally use this command to remove the failing repo(s):

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:{failing ppa}
```

for the example here it will look like this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:upubuntu-com/web
```

Comment: I have no failing repo's `sudo apt-get update | grep "Failed"` returns nothing, but I have the same error as the OP.

Answer (score 10):

Alternative, it is also possible to cut the crap in rvm. I edited requirements_debian_update_system() in file /usr/share/rvm/scripts/functions/requirements/ubuntu like this:

```
  requirements_debian_update_system()
  {
  echo "*fake* apt-get update"
  #  __rvm_try_sudo apt-get --quiet --yes update ||
  #  {
  #    typeset __ret=$?
  #    case ${__ret} in
  #      (100)
  #        rvm_error "There has been error while updating 'apt-get', please give it some time and try again later.
  #404 errors should be fixed for rvm to proceed. Check your sources configured in:
  #    /etc/apt/sources.list
  #    /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list
  #"
  #        ;;
  #    esac
  #    return ${__ret}
  #  }
  }
```

Comment: The path provided was not the same for me. The correct path should be $rvm_path/scripts/functions/requirements/ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for this, `rvm` is clearly overstepping its boundaries here. One failure during an `apt-get update` is _not_ a valid reason to throw toys out of the pram and give up on an install.

Answer (score 6):

This happened to me as well when I was trying to install a version of Ruby as a non-sudoer user. However, when I logged in as my admin user (with sudo privileges) and ran `sudo apt-get update | grep "Failed"` I would get no errors and, yet, `rvm install x.x.x` would still result in asking for a password (when I ran `rvm install` as the non-sudoer user.)

I was banging my head with this for a while because I didn't want my rvm (regular user) user to have sudo privileges. Then after some putzing around on Google I figured out that I could log in as my admin user.

Go through the steps of installing RVM for that user (as per their [documentation](https://rvm.io/)):

> $ gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3
>
> $ \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
>
> $ source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm

Then (as the admin user) jump straight into installing the RVM required packages:

`$ rvm requirements`

at which point it asks for my sudo password and installs the required apt packages for the entire system after I enter my password.

Then I log off from server as admin user and log back in as rvm user (with no sudo privileges) and try to install a version of Ruby.

`$ rvm install x.x.x`

and now it works.

Comment: This was the simplest solution for me.

Comment: I just ended up adding user to sudoers.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need of apt-get to install rvm and to use it !

Just curl (apt-get install curl)

Launch `\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby`

and `rvm install 2.1.1` or another ruby's version and it works ;)

gem update etc...

RVM will be independent of apt-get so you'll have no longer issu.

For more informations : `https://rvm.io/rvm/install`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. If none of the other answers work try this. I ran the following command to fix it:

`sudo apt-get -f install`

Then I remembered that I failed installing a package earlier that day. What this command did was resolve the dependencies on that package and allowed RVM to do its thing.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried

sudo apt-get update and found some of them are failing; for example..

Err http://extras.ubuntu.com raring/main Sources
  404  Not Found

I went ahead and deleted those items from the list here..

sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list

It worked!

Answer (score 0):

I was getting an error similar to this while running `curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby`. It took a while but I finally realised that I had synaptic open: the installer couldn't run because apt was locked

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting this error when my working directory was inside a mounted dir.

The fix was just to:

`cd ~`

I figured this out by seeing this at the bottom of a sudo apt-get update

`E: Unable to change to /path/to/my/current/directory/ - chdir (13: Permission denied)`

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error.I tried most of above answers but none works for me, so i just change server

1. Goto directory etc/apt
2. click on Sources.list
3. Change the server to us or some else server
4. Reload (it will update your cache from that server)
5. Then run `sudo apt-get update`

Answer (score 0):

this problem caused in `apt-get update` so you have to disable the PPA :

> System Settings>Software & Updates>Other Software

then reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

In my case rvm missed some linux packages, which couldnt be installed without sudo. There were no apt-get install errors at all.

When running rvm install ruby x.x.x with sudo, rvm installed packages required to build ruby and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Issue - requirements_debian_update_system ruby-2.2.2 error

I also had the same issue. I found info on this link 
[Click Here](http://www.sachingevariya.com/2015/08/requirementsdebianupdatesystem-ruby-222.html)

I followed this and resolved my issue. Was able to install ruby as

```
rvm install 2.2
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Before installing ruby must be done update:

apt is preferred over apt-get for interactive use in recent Ubuntu versions and apt should fix by:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

Or with apt-get may be used --allow-releaseinfo-change

```
sudo apt-get --allow-releaseinfo-change update
```

2) After successfully installation, for example ruby-2.3.1:

```
rvm install 2.3.1
```

Answer (score -1):

```
apt install libc6:amd64 libc6:amd64 libc6 libc6-dev:amd64 libc6-dev libc-dev-bin libc-bin man-db libc-dev-bin libc6-dev:amd64
```

***thats work fine for me ^^***

Answer (score -1):

The problem is with your sources configured in:

```
/etc/apt/sources.list
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list
```

So to check the errors you have to run this command and need to find that which PPA is firing errors:

```
sudo apt-get update | grep "Failed"
```

Then to resolve this error you have to press the Windows key and need to search "Software & Updates".

Then open it and go into Other Software there you can see some URLs which is failed while update.

Then uncheck those URLs from this and close this window and then do

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Finally, you can install ruby with

```
rvm install 2.4
```

PS: You can change the version you want to install ruby.