# Installing latest RUBY with rvm gives error on Ubuntu

Tags: ruby, rvm

Getting the following error when im trying to install ruby-2.1.2

```
rvm install ruby-2.1.2
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
Found remote file https://rubies.travis-ci.org/ubuntu/12.04/x86_64/ruby-2.1.2.tar.bz2
Checking requirements for ubuntu.
Installing requirements for ubuntu.
Updating system................
Error running 'requirements_debian_update_system ruby-2.1.2',
showing last 15 lines of /usr/local/rvm/log/1400060285_ruby-2.1.2/update_system.log
++ case "${TERM:-dumb}" in
++ case "$1" in
++ [[ -t 2 ]]
++ return 1
++ printf %b 'There has been error while updating '\''apt-get'\'', please give it some time and try again later.
For 404 errors check your sources configured in:
    /etc/apt/sources.list
    /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list
\n'
There has been error while updating 'apt-get', please give it some time and try again later.
For 404 errors check your sources configured in:
    /etc/apt/sources.list
    /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list
++ return 100
```

Comment: Did you run that command as a superuser or as a normal user?

Comment: Yep, this is my local machine.

Comment: Update your system with apt-get upgrade and try agian

Comment: I'm getting the same issue.  After running rvm installation rvm still isn't in my PATH.

Comment: Answer is provided here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23650992/ruby-rvm-apt-get-update-error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install gawk g++ gcc make libc6-dev libreadline6-dev zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 autoconf libgdbm-dev libncurses5-dev automake libtool bison pkg-config libffi-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your rvm is older version,

Install the latest (v1.25.25) rvm using:

`$ \curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby`

then check the rubies available with this version:

`$ rvm list known`

then install the latest:

`$ rvm install ruby-2.1.2`

Note: Even if it does not show up in `rvm list known` it will try to download with the following message:

`Installing Ruby from source to: /home/<YOUR_USER_NAME>/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...`

Comment: UPDATE: Your destination could also be `/usr/local/rvm` instead of `/home/<YOUR_USER_NAME>/.rvm/`. The former is multi-user and latter is single user rvm installs

Answer (score 1):

This error in my case was cased because apt-get update gave a n error. After doing and manual sudo apt-get update I notices that one of the repos gave an error "W: Failed to fetch". After editing the repo list and removing the one that gave the error I was able to install.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. I went to "System->Preferences->Software & Updates", and disabled the PPA repositories that were generating the errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this for install latest ruby

```
rvm mount -r https://rvm.io/binaries/ubuntu/12.04/x86_64/ruby-1.9.3-p194.tar.bz2
```

for more help

```
rvm help mount
```

Comment: OP is asking for RVM is not getting installed . your ans is not properly for that question

Answer (score 0):

I tried most of above answers but none works for me, so i just change server
If you are using rvm for ruby then this will work.

1. Goto directory etc/apt
2. click on Sources.list
3. Change the server to us or some else server
4. Reload (it will update your cache from that server)
5. Then run `sudo apt-get update`
6. Finally run  `rvm install 2.3.0`