# Error when install ruby-2.3.0 with rvm

Tags: ruby, rvm

I am trying to install `ruby-2.3.0` with rvm, but it has an error

```
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: ubuntu/12.10/x86_64/ruby-2.3.0.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for ubuntu.
Installing requirements for ubuntu.
Updating system........................................
Error running 'requirements_debian_update_system ruby-2.3.0',
showing last 15 lines of /home/local/.rvm/log/1460088710_ruby-2.3.0/update_system.log
++ 1460088815.260685491 /scripts/functions/logging : rvm_pretty_print()  78 > case "${TERM:-dumb}" in
++ 1460088815.263259956 /scripts/functions/logging : rvm_pretty_print()  81 > case "$1" in
++ 1460088815.266028504 /scripts/functions/logging : rvm_pretty_print()  11 > [[ -t 2 ]]
++ 1460088815.270746572 /scripts/functions/logging : rvm_pretty_print()  83 > return 1
++ 1460088815.274824254 /scripts/functions/logging : rvm_error()  117 > printf %b 'There has been error while updating '\''apt-get'\'', please give it some time and try again later.
404 errors should be fixed for rvm to proceed. Check your sources configured in:
    /etc/apt/sources.list
    /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list
\n'
There has been error while updating 'apt-get', please give it some time and try again later.
404 errors should be fixed for rvm to proceed. Check your sources configured in:
    /etc/apt/sources.list
    /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list

++ 1460088815.278415072 /scripts/functions/requirements/ubuntu : requirements_debian_update_system(return 100
Requirements installation failed with status: 100.
```

How can I fix it?
Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23650992/ruby-rvm-apt-get-update-error

Comment: Thanks, but it not work with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of Quantal is no longer support for ubuntu 12.10. So I am changing references to `quantal` to `precise` in `/etc/apt/sources.list` and comment some `quantal` in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*` and run `apt-get update`
I fixed with me.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using below comment to install, if not try it

```
# Installing rvm
gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3

curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable

# Installing ruby
source /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm

rvm install ree-2.3.0

rvm use ree-1.8.7-2012.02
```

Comment: Yes, I have already installed `rvm` by this way. Btw, I've solved this error.