# Install ruby requirements on ubuntu

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, jekyll

I'm trying the installation steps from http://sharadchhetri.com/2014/06/30/install-jekyll-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts/

```
linux@ubuntu:~$ rvm requirements

Checking requirements for ubuntu.
Installing requirements for ubuntu.
Updating system...................
Error running 'requirements_debian_update_system ',
showing last 15 lines of /home/jobi/.rvm/log/1464166761/update_system.log
+ case "${TERM:-dumb}" in
+ case "$1" in
+ [[ -t 2 ]]
+ return 1
+ printf %b 'There has been error while updating '\''apt-get'\'', please give it some time and try again later.
404 errors should be fixed for rvm to proceed. Check your sources configured in:
    /etc/apt/sources.list
    /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list
\n'
There has been error while updating 'apt-get', please give it some time and try again later.
404 errors should be fixed for rvm to proceed. Check your sources configured in:
    /etc/apt/sources.list
    /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list

+ return 100
Requirements installation failed with status: 100.
```

Why the above step get failing.. Please help

Comment: Have you tried with sudo? You won't succeed in running apt-get as a common user, because the configuration files are property of the root user.

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23650992/ruby-rvm-apt-get-update-error

Comment: Personally, I also get problems with rvm. I now use [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) and it's painless.

Answer (score 1):

The command it's failing on is one you can run from the command line:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

If that fails, then you would need to look into that, and that's not an rvm or Ruby problem at all.

I would do that, and then try `rvm requirements` again.