# How to update ruby from 2.0.0 to 2.2.2 in ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, ubuntu

I am using ubuntu 16.04, ruby 2.0.0, rails 4.0.13 and mongoDB 3.4.2.
I want to update ruby to 2.2.2 but I am getting error :

```
Error running 'requirements_debian_update_system ruby-2.2.6',
showing last 15 lines of /home/lakhvir/.rvm/log/1487593522_ruby-2.2.6/update_system.log
++ case "${TERM:-dumb}" in
++ case "$1" in
++ [[ -t 2 ]]
++ return 1
++ printf %b 'There has been error while updating '\''apt-get'\'', please give it some time and try again later.
404 errors should be fixed for rvm to proceed. Check your sources configured in:
    /etc/apt/sources.list
    /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list
\n'
There has been error while updating 'apt-get', please give it some time and try again later.
404 errors should be fixed for rvm to proceed. Check your sources configured in:
    /etc/apt/sources.list
    /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list

++ return 100
Requirements installation failed with status: 100.
```

Comment: Maybe this already answered link can help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23650992/ruby-rvm-apt-get-update-error

Comment: What steps did you follow to upgrade?

Comment: When I am using (sudo apt-get update | grep "Failed") command then I am getting (W:GPG error:http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.2 Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available:NO_PUBKEY D68FA50FEA312927
W:The repository 'http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.2 Release' is not signed.
E: Failed to fetch http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/xenial/mongodb-org/3.0/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you should upgrade your Rails version immediately:
[Ruby on Rails 4.0 End of Life was in January 2015.](https://medium.com/@nhance/ruby-on-rails-4-0-end-of-life-was-in-january-2015-ffd8df3ea5f4#.ijd0pxiwc)

As for the other error it looks like apt-get update is choking somehow.  I would try fixing that first before going through rvm.

```
apt-get update
```

and

```
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

(make sure you understand what these do before running them).  If you get errors there, make sure your

```
/etc/apt/sources.list
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list
```

files are all correct.