# rvm requirements not working

Tags: ruby, rvm, linux-mint

I'm using Linux Mint 17.3 and I'm trying to upgrade ruby to 2.4 using this guide: https://tecadmin.net/install-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu/

The problem is that when I get to the step "Install Ruby Dependencies" and run `rvm requirements`, I get this error:

```
Checking requirements for mint.
Installing requirements for mint.
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/rvm/log/1525898101’: Permission denied
tee: /usr/local/rvm/log/1525898101/update_system.log: No such file or directory
Updating system..................
Error running 'requirements_debian_update_system ',
please read /usr/local/rvm/log/1525898101/update_system.log
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.
```

Since I got "permission denied" when trying to write to a system directory, I next tried `sudo rvm requirements`, which gave me this error:

```
sudo: rvm: command not found
```

A few web searches later revealed that there's actually something called `rvmsudo`, but that doesn't help, either:

```
rvmsudo requirements
sudo: requirements: command not found
```

What do I need to fix in order to get `rvm requirements` to run without errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bypassing the standard warnings about abusing `sudo`, the `bash` hack

```
sudo `which rvm`
```

worked for me.

Comment: That just gives me sudo's usage instructions.

Comment: put your argument on the end of the line; `requirements`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this solution here ? RVM depends on apt-get update to return without any errors: [Ruby RVM apt-get update error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23650992/ruby-rvm-apt-get-update-error)

If you have errors running apt-get update, then the above link can fix your issues. The issue may be as mundane as one of your repositories being down for another, and unrelated, software on your computer