# ruby and rails return to earlier versions when I close and reopen terminal

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ubuntu, rvm, ubuntu-12.04

I'm trying to upgrade Ruby from 1.8.7 to the latest version and Rails from 2.3.14 to the latest version. I ran:

```
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby --autolibs=enable --auto-dotfiles
```

and then it tells me to run:

```
source /home/USER/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

in all of my open shell windows, which is just the one so I do that. If I type:

```
ruby -v
```

It tells me I have 2.0.0p195 which is okay (although I kinda wanted 1.9.2), but if I close that window, and type the same thing any time I open a shell window again, it tells me I only have 1.8.7. Something similar happens if I try installing Rails after installing Ruby this way.

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04

**EDIT:**

I'm using RVM. I installed it according to the answer from this stackoverflow question because it was originally a broken version (that's where my command from above comes from):

> [Installed Ruby 1.9.3 with RVM but command line doesn't show ruby -v](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9056008/installed-ruby-1-9-3-with-rvm-but-command-line-doesnt-show-ruby-v)

Comment: Why don't you use [Ruby version manager](https://rvm.io/)?

Comment: @MarekLipka this happens while using RVM

Comment: Right, I didn't notice. The answer is in the way. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
rvm use --default 2.0.0
```

It occurs probably because your default ruby version is 1.8.7. You can quickly check it with

```
rvm list
```

To install 1.9.2, simply type:

```
rvm install 1.9.2
```