# RVM is not creating a gemset with jruby

Tags: ruby, rvm, jruby

My RVM version is

> rvm -v
>
> rvm 1.6.9 by Wayne E. Seguin (wayneeseguin@gmail.com)
>   [https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/]

```
rvm rubies

   ruby-1.9.2-p180 [ x86_64 ]
   jruby-1.7.3 [ linux-amd64 ]
   jruby-1.6.1 [ linux-amd64-java ]
```

I tried to create gemset by commands

```
rvm use jruby-1.7.3
rvm gemset create 'mytest'
```

And when I see the gemset

```
rvm gemset list

gemsets for system (found in /usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/system)
   *
```

No gemset is create.
please guide me where is I am wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installed Ruby 1.9.3 with RVM but command line doesn't show ruby -v](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9056008/installed-ruby-1-9-3-with-rvm-but-command-line-doesnt-show-ruby-v)

Answer (score 0):

you are using very old version of rvm that comes from ubuntu package and is broken, use this answer to fix it https://stackoverflow.com/a/9056395/497756