# error installing ruby-rvm in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, rvm, dpkg

when i try to install ruby-rvm in ubuntu 12.04 using this command

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-rvm
```

it downloads the packages correctly but then gives this error

```
Setting up ruby-rvm (1.6.9-0ubuntu2) ...
dpkg-statoverride: error: syntax error: unknown group 'admin' in statoverride file
dpkg: error processing ruby-rvm (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ruby-rvm
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

the contents of stateoverride file are as follows

```
root mlocate 2755 /usr/bin/mlocate
hplip root 755 /var/run/hplip
root ssl-cert 710 /etc/ssl/private
root crontab 2755 /usr/bin/crontab
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should not install rvm this way, the package in ubuntu repositories is very old an contains multiple bugs, please check this instruction for a way to clean and install rvm properly: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9056395/497756