# RVM + rails 4 + whenever =?

Tags: cron, rvm, whenever

as the title suggests I am running

- rails 4
- Ruby 1.9.3-p0
- rvm 1.6.9
- whenever 0.8.3
- the project's gemset

I run `whenever -w` and get the appropriate setting in the `crontab`.
If I copy & paste that command all works out well.
`Cron` however has other opinion.

I tried following advice here http://danielsz.github.io/how-to-run-rvm-scripts-as-cron-jobs/index.html/ , but without much success.

Looks to me that `cron` fails to set the appropriate gemset.

How can I fix this?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all RVM 1.6.9 is very old version, you should update with

```
rvm get head
rvm reload
rvm get stable
```

But I'm afraid you might be using `ruby-rvm` package from ubuntu repositories, you should use then this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/9056395/497756 (yes this is necessary).

As for integration with cron - use wrappers and aliases:

```
rvm alias create my_app 1.9.3@my_app
rvm wrapper my_app --no-prefix --all
```

This assumed your application gems are installed in `1.9.3@my_app`, it created an alias `my_app` so it can be referenced in scripts so the scripts do not need to be changed when new ruby version is used.

The wrappers were created in `/path/to/rvm/wrappers/my_app/*` this are binary files automatically loading proper ruby environment for your application, they can be used in two ways:

- `export PATH=/path/to/rvm/wrappers/my_app:$PATH` and then simply call `bundle rake`
- call directly: `/path/to/rvm/wrappers/my_app/bundle rake`

If you use [rvm-capistrano](https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm-capistrano) it has a command to do the wrappers and alias creation for you => https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm-capistrano#create-application-alias-and-wrappers