# RVM install giving postgres error (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, rails-postgresql

I get a postgres error when I'm trying to install rvm for some odd reason.

```
$ sudo apt-get install ruby-rvm
```

Error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
ruby-rvm is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gir1.2-ubuntuoneui-3.0 libubuntuoneui-3.0-1
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
Setting up postgresql-9.1 (9.1.10-0ubuntu12.04) ...
 * Starting PostgreSQL 9.1 database server
   The PostgreSQL server failed to start. Please check the log output:
FATAL:  syntax error in file "/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/postgresql.conf" line 59, near token ".1"
[fail]
invoke-rc.d: initscript postgresql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing postgresql-9.1 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
 Errors were encountered while processing:
 postgresql-9.1
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 1):

`ruby-rvm` is no more maintained package and you should not use it, for more details check https://stackoverflow.com/a/9056395/497756

Answer (score 0):

You might want to install these packages and try again

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.1 libpq-dev
```

Edit:

I always install rvm like this

Dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get -y install gawk libgdbm-dev pkg-config libffi-dev build-essential openssl \
libreadline6 libreadline6-dev curl git-core zlib1g zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 \
libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev autoconf libc6-dev libncurses5-dev automake libtool bison subversion python \
postgresql postgresql-contrib libpq-dev nodejs
```

And rails:

```
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails
```