# Not able to use ruby 2.1.0 even after installation

Tags: ruby, rvm, bundle

I downloaded and installed ruby 2.1.0.

Here's the output of **ruby -v**:

> ruby 2.1.0p0 (2013-12-25 revision 44422) [i686-linux]

So I specified the same version in my Gemfile. But when I run **bundle**, I get:

> Your Ruby version is 1.9.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.0p0

And to add on, **rvm list** does not give me the list of rubies:

```
rvm rubies


$>
```

I'm new to Ruby and all I want to do is use the new Ruby version. Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: You should use rvm to install ruby `rvm install 2.1.0`

Comment: at first type `rvm reset`, then `rvm list`, say if will not help

Comment: @Jani: Why should we do that?

Comment: `rvm use system` would use system ruby (the one you installed manually) and not one installed via rvm, however preferably install it via rvm (`rvm install 2.1.0`)

Comment: Here's the output of **rvm install 2.1.0**: `ERROR: Unknown ruby interpreter version: '2.1.0'
ERROR: Either the ruby interpreter is unknown or there was an error!.`

Comment: @AGS rbenv manages the different rubys in far more simpler ways.

Comment: @Jani, but rbenv itself does not install rubies, which gets a lot more confusing for beginning users, and if you are in a search for simplicity you should checkout chruby => https://github.com/postmodern/chruby and ruby-install => https://github.com/postmodern/ruby-install

Comment: Found the [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9056008/installed-ruby-1-9-3-with-rvm-but-command-line-doesnt-show-ruby-v/9056395#9056395). It seems Ubuntu does something to RVM that causes it to break. Reinstalled using the instructions from the answer given to that question and things started working out from there. Thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 1):

starting with http://rvm.io/help you can find http://cheat.errtheblog.com/s/rvm and http://screencasts.org/episodes/how-to-use-rvm - make sure to read / watch both - in few minutes they should make it all clear.