# Trying to install ruby and ruby on rails 4 on Ubuntu?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

So I'm following this guide at http://railsapps.github.io/installrubyonrails-ubuntu.html

and I install RVM without a hitch. However, when I check for the version of ruby that I installed via:

```
ruby -v
```

I got the following:

```
The program 'ruby' can be found in the following packages:
 * ruby1.8
 * ruby1.9.1
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

I tried to install ruby manually through RVM:

```
rvm install ruby
```

However, it merely told me that ruby had already been installed.

Has anyone encountered this same issue?

TIA

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installed Ruby 1.9.3 with RVM but command line doesn't show ruby -v](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9056008/installed-ruby-1-9-3-with-rvm-but-command-line-doesnt-show-ruby-v)

Comment: Sorry I never get that message and you can try with these urls these may help you for installing rvm and ruby installation and rails installation

rvm :
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin-with-rvm
red hat:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-on-centos-6-with-rvm

Comment: @HithamS.AlQadheeb: I followed that and did not manage to resolve my problem prior to my asking of this question

Comment: @Veeru: Thanks! The first link helped a lot!!

Comment: Not entirely. Sorry for not responding. When I restarted my system, ruby was once again unavailable. However, I went ahead and solved my own problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try with these urls these may help you for installing rvm and ruby installation and rails installation

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin-with-rvm

This may help you

Answer (score 0):

After installing rvm, if you installed it as root, try

```
source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh
```

If you installed as user, try

```
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

Answer (score 0):

I've definitely been there. I created a script to help me install ruby on remote machines. This was made for new EC2 instances, but maybe it will work.

https://github.com/jubrad/install_ruby

If you do want to use it you'll likely have to remove rvm and your rubies first.
   -https://rvm.io/rubies/removing
   -sudo apt-get remove rvm

best of luck.