# ruby install rvm not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to install rvm and geting problem. Here is my command which i run in ubnto 2.10 How can i do this?

```
root@jaskaran-Vostro-1550:/home/jaskaran# rvm install 2.1.0
The program 'rvm' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
apt-get install ruby-rvm
root@jaskaran-Vostro-1550:/home/jaskaran# apt-get install ruby-rvm
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ruby-rvm
```

Comment: do this `source ~/.bashrc` then do `rvm install 2.1.0`

Comment: You have installed the rvm just add it to the path if its not there or  reload the bashrc file as shown above by @ParitoshPiplewar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this instead to install RVM:

```
curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash
```

You can refer to official **[RVM](http://rvm.io/rvm/install)** Installation Page.

Once RVM is successfully installed, make it available in the current shell:

```
source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh
```

Then you can install the Ruby version you want:

`rvm install 2.1.0` to install Ruby version 2.1.0.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to clean up your environment first just like this post tells you to: [Installed Ruby 1.9.3 with RVM but command line doesn't show ruby -v](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9056008/installed-ruby-1-9-3-with-rvm-but-command-line-doesnt-show-ruby-v/9056395#9056395)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this:

**sudo apt-get install rvm**

next you will have to source the
**source /home/username/.rvm/scripts/rvm**

after then you can go ahead and install by running

**rvm install version**

Hope this help  another person.