# Ruby issue when installing Umpire on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, heroku, rubygems, graphite

I am currently trying to get https://github.com/heroku/umpire working locally on my Ubuntu machine with graphite. 
I have done the following steps on version 12.04 of Ubuntu:

1. git clone https://github.com/heroku/umpire
2. cd umpire
3. sudo apt-get install ruby-rvm
4. sudo rvm install ruby-1.9.2-p180
5. sudo apt-get install ruby-bundler

The line that is producing the error in the Gemfile:

```
gem 'rack-timeout', git: "https://github.com/freeformz/rack-timeout.git"
```

This is the error that I am getting in the terminal:

```
/home/vagrant/umpire/Gemfile:9:in `evaluate': compile error (SyntaxError)
/home/vagrant/umpire/Gemfile:9: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting $end
gem 'rack-timeout', git: "https://github.com/freeformz...
                    ^
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/definition.rb:17:in `build'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler.rb:136:in `definition'
```

I've been trying to fix this for a while but I am not particularly familiar with Ruby. Does anyone know how fix this?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not use the apt provided rvm. It's old and broken in a few ways AFAICT.

Start here: [Installed Ruby 1.9.3 with RVM but command line doesn't show ruby -v](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9056008/installed-ruby-1-9-3-with-rvm-but-command-line-doesnt-show-ruby-v/9056395#9056395)

Once I did that I was able to install the right version of ruby for my user and bundle install...

```
vagrant@ubuntu-12:~$ cd umpire/
RVM used your Gemfile for selecting Ruby, it is all fine - Heroku does that too,
you can ignore these warnings with 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore /home/vagrant/umpire/Gemfile'.
To ignore the warning for all files run 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore allGemfiles'.

ruby-1.9.3-p547 is not installed.
To install do: 'rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p547'

vagrant@ubuntu-12:~/umpire$ rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p547
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
Found remote file https://rvm.io/binaries/ubuntu/12.04/x86_64/ruby-1.9.3-p547.tar.bz2
Checking requirements for ubuntu.
Requirements installation successful.
ruby-1.9.3-p547 - #configure
ruby-1.9.3-p547 - #download
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 11.3M  100 11.3M    0     0  1851k      0  0:00:06  0:00:06 --:--:-- 2137k
ruby-1.9.3-p547 - #validate archive
ruby-1.9.3-p547 - #extract
ruby-1.9.3-p547 - #validate binary
ruby-1.9.3-p547 - #setup
ruby-1.9.3-p547 - #gemset created /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@global
ruby-1.9.3-p547 - #importing gemset /home/vagrant/.rvm/gemsets/global.gems....................................
ruby-1.9.3-p547 - #generating global wrappers........
ruby-1.9.3-p547 - #gemset created /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547
ruby-1.9.3-p547 - #importing gemsetfile /home/vagrant/.rvm/gemsets/default.gems evaluated to empty gem list
ruby-1.9.3-p547 - #generating default wrappers........

vagrant@ubuntu-12:~/umpire$ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching https://github.com/freeformz/rack-timeout.git
Installing rake 10.1.1
Installing addressable 2.3.5
Installing aggregate 0.2.2
Installing safe_yaml 0.9.7
Installing crack 0.4.1
Installing diff-lcs 1.2.5
Installing excon 0.31.0
Installing multipart-post 1.2.0
Installing faraday 0.8.9
Installing multi_json 1.8.4
Installing librato-metrics 1.3.0
Installing rack 1.5.2
Installing puma 2.7.1
Installing rack-protection 1.5.1
Installing rack-ssl 1.3.3
Installing rack-test 0.6.2
Using rack-timeout 0.1.0beta2 from https://github.com/freeformz/rack-timeout.git (at master)
Installing rspec-core 2.14.7
Installing rspec-expectations 2.14.4
Installing rspec-mocks 2.14.4
Installing rspec 2.14.1
Installing scrolls 0.3.3
Installing tilt 1.4.1
Installing sinatra 1.4.4
Installing webmock 1.16.1
Installing yajl-ruby 1.2.0
Using bundler 1.6.2
Your bundle is complete!
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
vagrant@ubuntu-12:~/umpire$
```