# rvm fix path: command not found?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu

I have a problem with virtual machine (Ubuntu) installation for the course from edX Berkeley CS169.1x SaaS. I am using the Ubuntu virtual machine provided by the authors (http://www.saasbook.info/bookware-vm-instructions). Basically, I am working on Homework 2, and I followed the instruction and installed the required system successfully yesterday(https://github.com/saasbook/hw-rails-intro). However, today when I open the terminal, some errors show up:

> __rvm_fix_path_from_gem_path: command not found
>
> rvm_is_a_shell_function: command not found

and saying: The program 'rails' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:

```
sudo apt-get install rails
```

Then I reinstalled everything again, but the same problem shows up again after restarting my pc or even opening a new terminal.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed RVM?. If not then install RVM first then install rails with `gem install rails`

Comment: Yes, I did. RVM 1.6.9. The point is I installed all the required gems, and I even can work on my home work, but when restart my PC or even open a new terminal, the error show up. It seems somehow it can not locate or 'forget' the installed gems.

Comment: looks like your RVM is too old. First upgrade rvm via stable it then try again. Here is link https://rvm.io/rvm/upgrading

Comment: Thanks, I just tried upgrade rvm according to the provided link. I got the message as follows:     It looks you are one of the happy Ubuntu users,
RVM packaged by Ubuntu is old and broken,
follow this link for details how to fix:

  http://stackoverflow.com/a/9056395/497756